# HttpClient: Determine empty entity in response

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I'm wondering how to determine an empty http response.
With empty http response I mean, that the http response will only have set some headers, but contains an empty http body.

For example: I do a HTTP POST to an webserver, but the webserver will only return an status code for my HTTP POST and nothing else.

The problem is, that I have written a little http framework on top of apache HttpClient to do auto json parsing etc. So the default use case of this framework is to make a request and parse the response. However if the response does not contain data, like mentioned in the example above, I will ensure that my framework skip json parsing.

So I do something like this:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uriRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null){
    InputStream in = entity.getContent();
    // json parsing
}
```

However entity is always != null. And also the retrieved inputstream is != null. Is there a simple way to determine if the http body is empty or not?

The only way I see is that the server response contains the Content-Length header field set to 0.
But not every server set this field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `HttpClient`, `getEntity()` *can* return null. See [the latest samples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html).

However, there's a difference between an *empty* entity, and *no* entity. Sounds like you've got an *empty* entity. (Sorry to be pedantic -- it's just that HTTP is pedantic. :) With respect to detecting empty entities, have you tried reading from the entity input stream? If the response is an empty entity, you should get an immediate EOF.

Do you need to determine if the entity is empty without reading any bytes from the entity body? Based on the code above, I don't think you do. If that's the case, you can just wrap the entity `InputStream` with a [`PushbackInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html) and check:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uriRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if(entity != null) {
    InputStream in = new PushbackInputStream(entity.getContent());
    try {
        int firstByte=in.read();
        if(firstByte != -1) {
            in.unread(firstByte);
            // json parsing
        }
        else {
            // empty
        }
    }
    finally {
        // Don't close so we can reuse the connection
        EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(entity);
        // Or, if you're sure you won't re-use the connection
        in.close();
    }
}
```

It's best not to read the entire response into memory just in case it's large. This solution will test for emptiness using constant memory (4 bytes :).

**EDIT**: Pedantry follows below.

From [Section 4.3 of the HTTP/1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3):

> For response messages, whether or not a message-body is included with
> a message is dependent on both the request method and the response
> status code (section 6.1.1). All responses to the HEAD request method
> MUST NOT include a message-body, even though the presence of entity-
> header fields might lead one to believe they do. All 1xx
> (informational), 204 (no content), and 304 (not modified) responses
> MUST NOT include a message-body. All other responses do include a
> message-body, although it MAY be of zero length.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The PushbackInputStream was the key, otherwise the inputstream will be consumed for checking and can not be used for reading the real data. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it was useful! `PushbackInputStream` is *super* useful.

Comment: In my case, I'm always getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset once I try to read from input stream of response with unknown content length. So I guess using PushbackInputStream is not an approach that is universal enough.  Checking Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding headers seems to be the right way of dealing with the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the class [`EntityUtils`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) to get the response as String. If it returns the empty string, then the response is empty.

```
String resp = EntityUtils.toString(client.execute(uriRequest).getEntity())
if (resp == null || "".equals(resp)) {
    // no entity or empty entity
} else {
    // got something
    JSON.parse(resp);
}
```

The assumption here is that, for sake of code simplicity and manutenibility, you don't care to distinguish between empty entity and no entity, and that if there is a response, you need to read it anyway.

Comment: Thank you anyway, but I prefer to work with input streams, because I also parse binary data like images

Comment: Also EntityUtils.toString throws an exception if its parameter is null. Sometimes this is not an appropriate behavior.